# Google maps API v3 show local entry

Tags: google-maps

I'd like to show a single specific local business on a google map (API V3) with the associated reviews, directions etc.

[Example](http://www.ezfurn.com.au/pages/?ParentPageID=24&PageID=28)

Can anyone point me in the right direction for doco or code examples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a single known business, you can use the business's CID (customer ID) code to display the map with local info.

La Palma in San Francisco:

http://maps.google.com/maps?cid=16753855001018446220

How do you get the CID?  Do a search for the business on Google Maps and find the business in the result list.  The CID will appear in the query arguments of the URL for the listing.

*Note:* This isn't in the Google Maps API, or documented anywhere I could find.

Comment: Thanks mate, thats the sort of thing I was after.

Comment: This no longer works. You get a blank map with the error message: "We could not understand the location"

Answer (score 1):

Cool street view too | http://maps.google.com/?cid=16753855001018446220&layer=c&t=h&z=20&cbll=37.75302,-122.410094&panoid=jn-nsgokdWNvXYRDjgqb-w&cbp=12,142.79,,0,0.54